# How can I avoid receiving a copy of an email I send to an Exchange distribution list using Microsoft Outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange, distribution-list

We use outlook 2010 and there is a distribution list in the global address book and I am part of it. Whenever I send something to it I always get a copy of this e-mail into my inbox. Is there a way to stop this? I have a copy of the message I sent in the 'sent' folder, I don't need to be getting the messages I've sent to this DL. Is this doable?

Comment: You could set up a rule that automatically discards all arriving emails with you as the Sender. (Unless you typically send yourself emails for other purposes).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As indicated by other comments, the solution is to create a rule that will delete the messages for you. Below are the steps to do this using Outlook 2010, 2013, or 2016. *Note: this applies to people using Outlook to connect to an Exchange server account. Other types of distribution lists may behave differently.*

Using Outlook 2010/2013/2016:

1. Click the **File** tab.
2. Click **Manage Rules & Alerts**.
3. In the **Rules and Alerts** dialog, select the **E-mail Rules** tab and click the **New Rule...** button.
4. In the **Rules Wizard** dialog, select `Apply rule on messages I receive` and then click **Next**.
5. Check the `from people or public group` condition. In the lower box, click the `people or public group` link and then select your own name in the **Rule Address** dialog. Click **OK** to close the **Rule Address** dialog, and then click **Next**.
6. Check the following actions:

   - `delete it`
   - `stop processing more rules`
7. Click **Next**.
8. (Optional) If you routinely send yourself mail for other reasons, you may want to check the `except if my name is in the To or Cc box` exception.
9. Click **Next**.
10. In the last step, specify the name for your rule.
11. (Optional) If you want to delete existing emails already in your inbox, check `Run this rule now on messages already in "Inbox"`.
12. Click **Finish** to close the **Rules Wizard**.
13. Click **OK** to close the **Rules and Alerts** dialog.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking up the same question and the only solution I could think of at the end is **setting up Outlook rule** to delete email messages **immediately** that are sent from the same account. So far the only option to keep inbox clean.