# In Outlook, how can I avoid receiving my own emails that I send to a group?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, email-filter

When I send an email from Outlook to a Google Group, I receive this email myself, so that I have two copies of the same message.
Based on [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/615462/how-can-i-avoid-receiving-a-copy-of-an-email-i-send-to-an-exchange-distribution), I tried to add a rule that automatically deletes emails from myself.
But it did not work - probably because, in the message from Google Group, the "From" field is not my own email - it is "my-group@googlegroups.com on behalf of my-email@outlook.com".

Is there a way to create a rule that automatically deletes such messages? I did not find an "on behalf of" field in the Inbox Rules setting.

I am using Outlook 365 web application.

Comment: Create a second group for you to send from that does not include your own email address. I do this fairly frequently to avoid the issue you are having.

Comment: @John The google-group that I want to send to does not allow me to send unless I am in the group. How can a second group solve this issue?

Comment: Try a group within Outlook itself if you can

Answer (score 0):

Change your rule to capture items that are consistent in the emails that you do not want, and are not in the emails that you do want.

In your question, you noted that the emails that you do not want have "my-group@googlegroups.com on behalf of my-email@outlook.com". Use this to create your rule

Comment: In what field of the rule should I put this string? I tried to put it in the From field of the rule, but it did not work, since this field accepts only email addresses, so the string "on behalf of..." generated an error "The specified user wasn't found or is invalid".

Comment: Oh ok, I took a look and that doesn't work directly but it can find information in the header: Try using the rule condition "with specific words in the message header". I can't test directly has I do not have 365. @Erel Segal-Halevi

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get rules to work when the email was from myself (I didn't send it, it was automatically created on my behalf by a tool as having come from me, but there was no "on behalf" anywhere in the header to indicate this or filter on).  Scanning over the full headers, it looked like the email came directly from me (even though it did not), and the rule generation process thought so too.  The rule looks like it *should* work, but it does not.  There were no errors, it simply did not move the email to where I had told it to.

I wound up having to delete the "from people or public group" filter that had my own email address in it and, instead, enter my email address in the "with specific words in the sender's address".

This looks like a weird bug to me, but at least the solution was reasonably straightforward.